# Slider with Javascript, starts with the last element, how do I make it start with normal order?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a slider with javascript without using ready libraries, all is cool but the sliders start with the last element then loop from the beginning, not from the beginning as it should be, I would like it to start with image one then two,, etc, it starts with image three then one, two, ,, you can check it here if you run the code:

```js
     let sliderImages=document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
     arrowRight=document.querySelector('#right-arrow'),
     arrowLeft=document.querySelector('#left-arrow'),
     current =0;
     
     
    function reset() {
        for ( i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease-in 0s";
        sliderImages[i].style.opacity= "0";    
           }
    }
    
       function slideRight() {
        reset();
        sliderImages[current].style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease-in 0s";
        sliderImages[current].style.opacity= "1.0"; 
     
        current++;
    }
    
    
    
           function mainLoop() {
             setInterval( function () {
               if (current === sliderImages.length ) {
                   current = 0
               }
               slideRight();

           },2000);
           }
   mainLoop();
```

```css
body, #slider, .wrapper, .slide-content{
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
.slide{
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
   position: absolute;

}
.slide1{
    background-color: darkseagreen;
   
}
.slide2{
    background-color: rgb(41, 241, 41);
    
}
.slide3{
    background-color: rgb(167, 180, 48);
}
.slide-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    

}
.slide-content span{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 6rem;
}
.arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
    border-style: solid;

}

#left-arrow{
border-width: 20px 25px 20px 0px;
border-color: transparent  #fff  ;
left: 0%;
margin-left: 30px;
z-index: 3;
}

#right-arrow{
    border-width: 20px 0px 20px 25px ;
    border-color: transparent  #fff  ;
    right: 0%;
    margin-right: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>slider</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper"> 
        <div id="left-arrow" class="arrow"></div>
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="slide slide1">
                <div class="slide-content">
                    <span>Image One</span>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="slide slide2">
                <div class="slide-content">
                    <span>Image two</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide3">
                <div class="slide-content">
                    <span>Image three</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right-arrow" class="arrow"></div>
    </div>



    <script src="js.js" > </script>

</body>
</html>
```

as you can see, it starts with "image three" i want to understand why it's like this, also, what do I need to do to make it proceed in order, any ideas ?

Comment: Can you attack a plunk for your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the css

```
.slide1{
    background-color: darkseagreen;

}
.slide2{
    background-color: rgb(41, 241, 41);
    opacity:0;

}
.slide3{
    background-color: rgb(167, 180, 48);
    opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript styles take a bit to do anything, and slides are visible by default: you will only see the topmost, which, with no z-index defined, will be the bottom html tag.

To make them unseen by default,

```
.slide { opacity: 0 }
```

To make the first one show up, you can add to your mainLoop function:

```
sliderImages[current].style.opacity = "1.0";
```

I've also had to update early to make the first transition happen in time:

```
// I've made this code a function in order to reuse it:
function update() {
  if (current === sliderImages.length) {
    current = 0
  }
  slideRight();
}

function mainLoop() {

  // The one image that is seen at the beginning: 
  sliderImages[current].style.opacity = "1.0";

  // Update early:
  update();

  setInterval(update, 2000);
}
```

```js
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
  arrowRight = document.querySelector('#right-arrow'),
  arrowLeft = document.querySelector('#left-arrow'),
  current = 0;


function reset() {
  for (i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease-in 0s";
    sliderImages[i].style.opacity = "0";
  }
}

function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current].style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease-in 0s";
  sliderImages[current].style.opacity = "1.0";

  current++;
}

function update() {
  if (current === sliderImages.length) {
    current = 0
  }
  slideRight();
}

function mainLoop() {
  
  // The one image that is seen at the beginning: 
  sliderImages[current].style.opacity = "1.0";
  
  // Update early:
  update();
  
  setInterval(update, 2000);
}
mainLoop();
```

```css
body,
#slider,
.wrapper,
.slide-content {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  /* No images are seen unless the style changes elsewhere */
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide1 {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.slide2 {
  background-color: rgb(41, 241, 41);
}

.slide3 {
  background-color: rgb(167, 180, 48);
}

.slide-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-content span {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  border-style: solid;
}

#left-arrow {
  border-width: 20px 25px 20px 0px;
  border-color: transparent #fff;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#right-arrow {
  border-width: 20px 0px 20px 25px;
  border-color: transparent #fff;
  right: 0%;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>slider</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="left-arrow" class="arrow"></div>
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="slide slide1">
        <div class="slide-content">
          <span>Image One</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
        <div class="slide-content">
          <span>Image two</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide3">
        <div class="slide-content">
          <span>Image three</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-arrow" class="arrow"></div>
  </div>



  <script src="js.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```